# When resizing window and then scrolling down, some elements get apart from each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I got a website (which I didn't made) that, when I resize to test responsiveness, it works normally, though, when getting it back and scrolling down (and then up), there seems to appear a gap between the header and the element under it.

Site: http://miriam.mx/index/

**Before resize and scroll:**

[image: **Before** resize and scroll]

**After resize and scroll:**

[image: **After** resize and scroll]

The site is using a lot of plugins and css:

[image: CSS files]

The thing is that I need some hint to solve it, since I'm not experienced with any of those CSS works yet.

Comment: You will need to post some code in order to get any help on this. Could be numerous reasons why. Either post the URL of the site or post some code here.

Comment: @fanfavorite Done, my friend.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? On Windows 10 in the latest Chrome and Firefox, I don't see any gap when scrolling.

Comment: @fanfavorite Chrome, latest, w10. You must resize it first like a mobile, then you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your sticky code. Looks like you are using [Sticky-Kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/). It's setting the height of the sticky div to a height bigger than your children elements. You are using 1.1.1, which they have 1.1.2 and that seems to add some support with auto adjusting when scrolling. You could also play around with the recalc settings.